# Can you skip an action widget in the foreground to another widget?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, lottie

I use Lottie above GoogleMap but I have problem I can't move GoogleMap In the frame of the picture
For example, when I use my fingers to move inside the map
It works fine but doesn't work at the edges of the Lottie
Can i skip Lottie to move map **as if it does not exist**

[image]

that my code

```
Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPosition),
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            initialCameraPosition: _cameraPosition,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            onCameraMoveStarted: () {
              setState(() {
                _controllerAnimation.forward(from: 0.0);
              });
            },
            onCameraIdle: () {
              setState(() {
                _controllerAnimation.forward(from: 0.65);
              });
            },
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
              _controller.complete(controller);
              _googleMapController = controller;
             

            },
          ),

Positioned(
              top: (mapHeight - iconSize - 180) / 2,
              right: (mapWidth - iconSize - 60) / 2,

              child: Lottie.asset("assets/json_assets/expanding_marker.json",
                  width: 128,
                  height: 160,
                  repeat: false,
                  controller: _controllerAnimation, onLoaded: (composition) {
                    _controllerAnimation.duration = composition.duration;
                    _controllerAnimation.forward(from: 0.50);
                    _controllerAnimation.stop(canceled: true);
                  })
          ),

])
```

If there is no way to solve, Is there another idea .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Positioned(
              top: (mapHeight - iconSize - 180) / 2,
              right: (mapWidth - iconSize - 60) / 2,

              child: 
IgnorePointer(ignoring: true, child:
Lottie.asset("assets/json_assets/expanding_marker.json",
                  width: 128,
                  height: 160,
                  repeat: false,
                  controller: _controllerAnimation, onLoaded: (composition) {
                    _controllerAnimation.duration = composition.duration;
                    _controllerAnimation.forward(from: 0.50);
                    _controllerAnimation.stop(canceled: true);
                  })
          ),),

])
```